# A quasilinear ode

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-analysis

I found the differential equation from a textbook (which is about differential games):

$$
\phi'(x)= \frac{1-r-2x}{2(x-x^2)/\phi(x)-M-2} 
$$
with initial condition $\phi(0)=0$. The textbook just says that the solution is
$$
\phi(x)=\frac{(1+r)x}{M+2}
$$
without any derivations.

It is easy to verify that the $\phi(x)$ given above is just the solution. However, I have no idea how to obtain the solution from the differential equation. The standard techniques like separable methods, first order linear equations or method of characteristic seems not working here.

Comment: I think you need the partial fractions method to separate the variables. Having everything $\phi$ related to the left, and everything $x$ related to the right.

Comment: One way to 'solve' this is to try the substitution $\phi(x)=x f(x)$, and then notice that $f(x)=(1+r)/(M+2)$ is a solution. But this is pretty much just the same as 'verifying' the solution.